# Python workaround with backoff for requests.exceptions.ConnectionError wont work

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello I'm using the requests module to check status of some parameters (true or false)

My problem:
The requests are done in a loop on the raspberry pi. At any time I get the following error message.

> > requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))

My goal is to have a workaround that the program dont stop with this error. The programm should go on.

[What I tried]:
So I tried the backoff function (https://pypi.org/project/backoff/) with max tries but this isnt the solution after a longer time I get the same error...

I think increasing the max tries is not the solution? Or I'm doing something wrong with backoff or what else should I do?

Here's my code snippet

```
import requests
import backoff

@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,max_tries=20)

while (True):
 x = requests.get('http://192.xxx/getPlainValue/javascript.0.sendPictureFlag')

 if (x.text == "true"):
   #print "save pic..."
   subprocess.call("raspistill -hf -vf -w 640 -h 480 -o /home/xxx/capture.jpg"", shell=True)
```

If the error occured I just notice it only when I didnt get the picture which I have requested. I have to restart the pi to reset the python programm.

Comment: why don't you try to use the `get` function inside `try-except` block?

Comment: That looks like a private IP address. Maybe your network is using that address space. Can you post the IP and your network address space?

Comment: @DroidX86

the flags are set through another Pi which working in the same network as the pi which doing the requests. Pi one 192.168.178.22  Second Pi 192.168.178.26

Comment: Can you ping that IP from your Pi?

Comment: @EntGriff 

before using the backoff function I used the try-except block. The problem was that I have to reset the flag to false after getting the picture. So sometime the flag wasn't set to false because of an except. Because of that a have to write another code which set all the flags to false after some excepts this make the program more complicated

Comment: @DroidX86

I tried ping that IP from the PI which runs the python request programm and it works fine without packet losses or something

Comment: Is there a way to count the connection error exceptions than wait some time without disturbing the rest of the programm an try it later?